# How can I set default value in Selected List in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, oop, enums

I am working on NopCommerce customization. I am using one selected list. And I want to make one value called Active is as default. My code is as below -

```
foreach (StatusEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusEnum)))
            {   
                newCycleModel.AvailableStatuses.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = item.ToString(),
                    Value = ((int)item).ToString(),
                });
            }
            test.AvailableStatuses.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = 'All', Value = "0" });
```

In StatusEnum i have two status as 'Active' and 'Close'

I want to put Active as default. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the `Selected` property based on the current item:

```
newCycleModel.AvailableStatuses.Add(new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = item.ToString(),
    Value = ((int)item).ToString(),
    Selected = (item == StatusEnum.Active)
}
```

This should result in the select item being selected if you use in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myddlist", Model.AvailableStatuses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Selected" property on the desired item to true.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)